# Creating multi-dimentional NetCDF in matlab

Tags: database, matlab, netcdf

I am attempting to create a four dimensional NetCDF structure of integers using matlab. This is my code so far...

```
mode = netcdf.getConstant('NETCDF4');
mode = bitor(mode,netcdf.getConstant('CLASSIC_MODEL'));
ncid = netcdf.create('USTEC_01_01_2010.nc',mode);
latDimId = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'latitude',51);
longDimId = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'longitude',101);
satDimId = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'satellite',33);
timeDimId = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'time',96);
varid = netcdf.defVar(ncid,'TECgrid','int',[latDimId longDimId satDimId timeDimId]);
```

My question is...How do I go about using putVar to insert values at specific four dimensional positions? FYI, this is my first time using NetCDF. Thanks in advance! -Dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version do you have? 
If you have a later version, look at these functions: [nccreate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nccreate.html) and ncwrite.

Or:

```
netcdf.endDef(ncid);
% Write one specific value to the last position. 
% See help netcdf.putVar. start is zero based.
% start argument's order corresponds to dimension definition above.
netcdf.putVar(ncid,varid,[50 100 32 95], 10);

netcdf.close(ncid);
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks...but now I realize it takes too long to add values individually. Is there a way to pass an entire matlab array (the same size as the netcdf structure)?

Comment: Also...how can I specify a specific point in the database to start copying the array? And how do I pull a specific 'hyper-chunk' of data out using netcdf.getVar? I can't seem to find much documentation online.

Comment: GPSmaster, did you type 'help netcdf.putVar'? There ought to be an example showing you how. (same for getVar). You can write in a whole array with just putVar(ncid, varid, <your data array>) - http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/netcdf.putvar.html

Comment: Got it sorted. I wasn't using netCDF.endDef(ncid) correctly. The feedback from errors in the netcdf library is cryptic. Took some trial and error to figure out what was wrong.